# How to extract week number in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a transdate column of varchar2 type which has the following entrees

```
01/02/2012
01/03/2012
```

etc.

I converted it in to date format in another column using to_date function. This is the format i got.

```
01-JAN-2012
03-APR-2012
```

When I'm trying to extract the weekno, i'm getting all null values.

select to_char(to_date(TRANSDATE), 'w') as weekno from tablename.

```
null
null
```

How to get weekno from date in the above format?

Comment: Never, ever, under no circumstance store dates in `varchar` columns. Just don't.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

After converting your `varchar2` date to a true `date` datatype, then convert back to `varchar2` with the desired mask:

```
to_char(to_date('01/02/2012','MM/DD/YYYY'),'WW')
```

If you want the week number in a `number` datatype, you can wrap the statement in `to_number()`:

```
to_number(to_char(to_date('01/02/2012','MM/DD/YYYY'),'WW'))
```

However, you have [several week number options](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php) to consider:

> | Parameter | Explanation |
> | --- | --- |
> | `WW` | Week of year (1-53) where week 1 starts on the first day of the year and continues to the seventh day of the year. |
> | `W` | Week of month (1-5) where week 1 starts on the first day of the month and ends on the seventh. |
> | `IW` | Week of year (1-52 or 1-53) based on the ISO standard. |

(See also [Oracle 19 documentation on datetime format elements](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-EAB212CF-C525-4ED8-9D3F-C76D08EEBC7A).)

Comment: So, I cant get weekno directly from the column whose format is `01-JAN-12` ?

Comment: @user2133404 If that column is a `date` datatype, then yes, in which case you only need to call `to_char(my_column,'WW')`, or with the desired format mask, on that column. If that column is not a true `date` datatype, then you are relying on implicit conversion to `date` (if that matches your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`) which is not as ideal.

Comment: we want Sunday to Saturday as one week,then how to get week number ? in the above query Monday to Sunday inclusively considered as one week

Comment: hi @Wolf i have requirement where in we need to consider one week as Sunday to Saturday and first week of year is 1 if the first day of year comes within Saturday inclusively

Comment: In most cases you'll want to use `'IW'`. For more info on the ISO standard see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date

Answer (score 5):

Try to replace 'w' for 'iw'.
For example:

```
SELECT to_char(to_date(TRANSDATE, 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 'iw') as weeknumber from YOUR_TABLE;
```

Comment: Still getting null values, I think the non numeric value for month is the cause of error ??

Comment: we want Sunday to Saturday as one week,then how to get week number ? in the above query Monday to Sunday inclusively considered as one week

Answer (score 0):

```
Select last_name, round (sysdate-hire_date)/7,0) as tuner 
  from employees
  Where department_id = 90 
  order by last_name;
```

Comment: Welcome to **Stack Overflow**, when posting answers please elaborate and explain why they work so people can learn from them, Thank you.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)

Answer (score -1):

Use `'dd-mon-yyyy'` if you are using the 2nd date format specified in your answer. Ex:

```
to_date(<column name>,'dd-mon-yyyy')
```