# get first day of a given week number in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Please help to derive first day of a given week_no in oracle not from given date.

Comment: what is your data and what have you tried?

Comment: Why the downvotes. This is a very clear and good question.
Input: the number of a week. Output. The first day of that week.

Comment: Please specify what you consider to be the first day of a week. Is that a sunday, or a monday or anything else? Also there are several definitions of a week number in Oracle. Please have a look at this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16530044/how-to-extract-week-number-in-sql

Comment: When you vote to close with reason "duplicate" it would be helpful to provide a link to the duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

You can try following query:-

```
SELECT NEXT_DAY(MAX(d), 'SUN') REQUESTED_SUN
FROM (SELECT TO_DATE('01-01-2015', 'DD-MM-YYYY') + (ROWNUM-1) d FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 366)
WHERE TO_CHAR(d, 'WW') = Your_Desired_WEEK_NO-1;
```

This might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 2):

Use this query

```
Select TRUNC (Trunc(sysdate,'yyyy')+(:num-1)*7,'IW') from duaL;
```

:num is number of week from year 2015, or put year what you need instead of sysdate.

Comment: This is not always correct: `Select TO_CHAR( TRUNC (Trunc(DATE '2012-01-01','yyyy')+(1-1)*7,'IW'), 'YYYY-IW' ) from duaL;` returns `2011-52` and not `2012-01`.

Comment: Select  TRUNC (Trunc(DATE '2012-01-01','yyyy')+(1-1)*7,'IW') from duaL; returns 26/12/2011 and it's actualy first day of first week of 01.01.2012

Comment: Yes - but its not the Monday of the first ISO week of 2012. The first ISO week is the week that contains the 4th January. You might need to specify how you are defining the first week if you are using a non-standard definition.

Comment: Yes, yes... But still we don't no actually what he want's so, that is only additional idea of realizing his task. Maybe he doesn't want "iso-week" :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function to get the date of the ISO week:

```
CREATE FUNCTION TO_ISO_WEEK_DATE(
  week NUMBER,
  year NUMBER
) RETURN DATE DETERMINISTIC
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN NEXT_DAY(
          TO_DATE( TO_CHAR( year, '0000' ) || '0104', 'YYYYMMDD' )
            - INTERVAL '7' DAY, 'MONDAY'
         )
         + ( week - 1 ) * 7;
END TO_ISO_WEEK_DATE;
/
```