# Adapt T-SQL code to PL/SQL code

Tags: t-sql, variables, plsql, size, declare

I just have a problem to convert some T-SQL code into  PL/SQL.

This is the original part of code :

```
SET @ISOweek= DATEPART(wk,@DATE)+1
    -DATEPART(wk,CAST(DATEPART(yy,@DATE) as CHAR(4))+'0104')
```

And after many research, i modify like that :

```
SET @ISOweek = TO_NUMBER(TRUNC(@DATE, 'IW')) + 1                
    - TO_NUMBER(TRUNC( (TO_CHAR(TRUNC(@DATE, 'YYYY'))) + '0104', 'IW'))
```

I can't test my code, that's why i come here for obtain your help. Can you say me if it's correct, or not? And what i've to modify because i'm a lost...
I read a lot of articles on this website, always helpfull.

Thank's for your answers

Cordialy,

Guillaume

The first problem it's ok, i've got a lot of responses and thnak's ;). 
But i've another problem :

My T-SQL script :

```
USE [myBD ]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

create function [Entity].[LPAD]
(
    @pad_value varchar(500),
    @pad_length int,
    @pad_with varchar(10) = ' '
)
returns varchar(5000)
as
BEGIN
    return ( replace(str(@pad_value,@pad_length),' ',@pad_with) )
END

GO
```

And i convert it in PL/SQL :

```
create OR REPLACE FUNCTION myBDOrcl.LPAD
(
    pad_value varchar2,
    pad_length number,
    pad_with varchar2 := ' '
)
return varchar2 
is retour varchar2(5000);

BEGIN

    retour :=  replace(TO_CHAR(pad_length, pad_value ), ' ', pad_with);
    return retour;

END;
```

I play the script and it's ok. BUT, i don't know how can I modify my variables : pad_value_varchar2 and the others, to specify the size...
I want to place a declare block, but it's not working....

Thank's for help guys

Comment: There is no `SET` in Oracle PL/SQL, variables are not prefixed with `@`, the string concatenation operator in SQL is `||` not `+` and the assignment operator is `:=` in PL/SQL. You should show us the complete stored procedure

Comment: Ok thank's for your answer, I can't show us the file on wich i work, because it's restricted. But can you say me how can i modify the orignal part of code so ? Because i'm not really an expert in PL/SQL... Thank's for your answer again

Comment: Have you tried [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4) set for Oracle 11g R2? You should be able to test PL/SQL there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extract week number in sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16530044/how-to-extract-week-number-in-sql)

Comment: What the tsql code is intended to do ? Get ISO week number from `DATE`-variable ?

Comment: Thank's all for your comments. The difficulty here it's to convert the Datepart(...) into a PL/SQL language. It's not solve my problem user272735, thank's for your comment. I've not try SQL Fiddle yet, i'm gonna take informations about that, thx HABO ! I'm thinking i've to return a number into ISOweek : DECLARE @ISOweek number(10)

Comment: Thx a_horse_with_no_name, with your informations i've correct my script ans it's better ;)

Comment: pad_value, pad_length and pad_with in your example are not variables, they are parameters passed into the procedure, and these don't take precision/scale. retour  is a local variable. (The convention is to have a newline after "is" to make things clearer.)