# get week number using oracle date function?

Tags: oracle, date

I used this query to get week number but getting wrong output of first week 
but actually its a second week of august-2016.

```
   select 
        to_char(TO_DATE('07-08-2016','dd-mm- rrrr'), 'w') week ,
      to_char(TO_DATE('07-08-2016','dd-mm- rrrr'), 'd') day-no,
      to_char(TO_DATE('07-08-2016','dd-mm- rrrr'), 'Day') Day 
      from dual
```

Comment: :8 date in second week not 7

Comment: What do   you consider als first day of week? Check your NLS_TERRITORY settings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract week number in sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16530044/how-to-extract-week-number-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

Read carefully:

> W - Week of month (1-5) where week 1 starts on **the first day** of the
>   month and ends on **the seventh**.

```
WITH t AS (SELECT TO_DATE ('07-07-2016', 'dd-mm-rrrr') d FROM DUAL)
SELECT TO_CHAR (d, 'w') week, 
       TO_CHAR (d, 'd') day_no, 
       TO_CHAR (d, 'Day') Day
  FROM t

WEEK DAY_NO DAY       
---- ------ ----------
1    5      Donnerstag
1 row selected.
```

It is possible to make it how do you want it, independent of NLS_TERRITORY:

```
WITH t AS (SELECT TO_DATE ('07-08-2016', 'dd-mm-rrrr') d FROM DUAL)
SELECT trunc(TO_CHAR (d+1, 'j')/7)-trunc(TO_CHAR (trunc(trunc(d,'mm'),'IW')+1, 'j')/7)+1 week,
       TO_CHAR (d, 'd') day_no, 
       TO_CHAR (d, 'Day') Day
  FROM t

      WEEK DAY_NO DAY       
---------- ------ ----------
         2 1      Sonntag   
1 row selected.
```

but it will be funny, when the first day of month is Saturday. You will have 6-th week in the month.

```
WITH t AS (SELECT TO_DATE ('30-11-2014', 'dd-mm-rrrr') d FROM DUAL)
SELECT trunc(TO_CHAR (d+1, 'j')/7)-trunc(TO_CHAR (trunc(trunc(d,'mm'),'IW')+1, 'j')/7)+1 week,
       TO_CHAR (d, 'd') day_no, 
       TO_CHAR (d, 'Day') Day
  FROM t

      WEEK DAY_NO DAY       
---------- ------ ----------
         6 1      Sonntag   
1 row selected.
```