# SQL ORACLE Get week numbers from multiple datetime rows

Tags: sql, oracle, date, datetime

I have 70.000 rows of data, including a date time column (YYYY-MM-DD HH24-MM-SS.). 
I want to split this data into 3 separate columns; Hour, day and Week number.

The date time column name is 'REGISTRATIONDATE' from the table 'CONTRACTS'.

This is what I have so far for the day and hour columns:

```
SELECT substr(REGISTRATIONDATE, 0, 10) AS "Date",
substr(REGISTRATIONDATE, 11, 9) AS "Hour"
FROM CONTRACTS;
```

**I have seen the options to get a week number for specific dates, this assignment concerns 70.000 dates so this is not an option.**

Comment: There is no standard definition of a "week number" for a date. What do you mean by it? Oracle has it's own understanding, though ... and if that what you want a good answer has already been supplied.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract week number in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16530044/how-to-extract-week-number-in-sql)

Comment: With 'week number' I mean that the year has 52 weeks and that I would like to have a column that notes the week number fitting the date (for example today 2017/06/03 is week number 22).

Comment: The answer provided may suffice, but also check the possible duplicate I linked. Much depends on how you define week 1. Does it begin on 1st Jan, or the first Monday in Jan or something else ... Try the various options and if none of them work, then come back specifying your need more exactly.

Comment: I have tried about 20 different option on how to do this at this point (I am learning SQL), every time I get options that are good for when you need the week number of a specific date. I have 70.000 dates so that might not be handy. 
What I mean by 'week number' is that the week 1 starts on the first Monday in Jan.
At this moment I already have my 'hour' and 'day' column. I would like to create a line of code that gets me a third row with the week number, fitting the date.
I hope this makes it more exactly.

Comment: Apologies for the time lag, had to get some stuff done. You've said it's a date-time field. Is it a text field in which you are storing a date-time or actually a date-time field? Since you're doing string functions on it, I'm guessing the latter.

Comment: My column 'REGISTRATIONDATE' has datatype VARCHAR2(128 BYTE) which has 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24-MM-SS' stored in it.

Comment: January 1, 2017, was a Sunday. What week number do you want to assign to this date? By your definition, it should belong to week 52 of year 2016. Do you just extract "52"? 2017 has its own week #52, will that cause a problem?

Comment: @mathguy, actually in this case it would be week 53, but your point still stands.

Comment: @SteveLovell - no, actually in this case it would be week 52, as I stated. Using the OP's definition, the first week of 2016 was from Monday Jan. 4 through Sunday Jan. 10. Week 52 (of 2016) started on Monday, Dec. 26 and ended on Sunday, January 1, 2017 (in the new year). My point and question stand exactly as written.

Comment: @mathguy, having done the math, you're quite right. That actually means my answer below doesn't handle cases where the 1st Jan date is initalised from the wrong year (I'd based my "53" comment on my output).

Comment: @HenrikeVaartstra, we haven't heard from you in a few days. Did you manage to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

You (the OP) still have to explain what week number to assign to the first few days in a year, until the first Monday of the year. Do you assign a week number for the prior calendar year? In a Comment I asked about January 1, 2017, as an example; that was a Sunday. The week from January 2 to January 8 of 2017 is "week 1" according to your definition; what week number do you assign to Sunday, January 1, 2017?

The straightforward calculation below assigns to it week number **0**. Other than that, the computation is trivial.

Notes: To find the Monday of the week for any given date `dt`, we can use `trunc(dt, 'iw')`. **iw** stands for ISO Week, standard week which starts on Monday and ends on Sunday.

Then: To find the first Monday of the year, we can start with the date January 7 and ask for the Monday of the week in which January 7 falls. (I won't explain that one - it's easy logic and it has nothing to do with programming.)

To input a fixed date, the best way is with the date literal syntax: `date '2017-01-07'` for January 7. Please check the Oracle documentation for "date literals" if you are not familiar with it.

So: to find the week number for any date `dt`, compute

```
1 + ( trunc(dt, 'iw') - trunc(date '2017-01-07', 'iw') ) / 7
```

This formula finds the Monday of the ISO Week of `dt` and subtracts the first Monday of the year - using Oracle date arithmetic, where the difference between two dates is the number of days between them. So to find the number of weeks we divide by 7; and to have the first Monday be assigned the number 1, instead of 0, we need to add 1 to the result of dividing by 7.

The other issue you will have to address is to convert your strings into dates. The best solution would be to fix the data model itself (change the data type of the column so that it is `DATE` instead of `VARCHAR2`); then all the bits of data you need could be extracted more easily, you would make sure you don't have dates like '2017-02-29 12:30:00' in your data (currently, if you do, you will have a very hard time making any date calculations work), queries will be a lot faster, etc. Anyway, that's an entirely different issue so I'll leave it out of this discussion.

Comment: Ah, that's much better! I'd delete my answer, except the advice about finding the bad data might still be useful. +1

Comment: Building on this, if there is no option to change the table so `REGISTRATIONDATE` really is a datetime field, if you sort the data issues and are happy with assigning week zero for dates in January before the first Monday in January, the code you'll want is: `1 + (trunc(to_date(REGISTRATIONDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24-MI-SS'), 'iw') - trunc(to_date(substr(REGISTRATIONDATE,1,4) || '-01-07','YYYY-MM-DD'), 'iw') ) / 7`

Comment: @SteveLovell - Good point about using `to_date()` instead of date literal; if the OP has dates in a diversity of years, the computation should be based on each date's specific year; and the date literal is just that, a literal - it can't use expressions, where the value of the expression is the year.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your REGISTRATIONDATE  if formatted as 'MM/DD/YYYY'

the simples  (and the faster  ) query is based  ond to to_char(to_date(REGISTRATIONDATE,'MM/DD/YYYY'),'WW')
(otherwise   convert you column in a proper date and perform the conversio to week number)

```
SELECT substr(REGISTRATIONDATE, 0, 10) AS "Date",
substr(REGISTRATIONDATE, 11, 9) AS "Hour",
to_char(to_date(REGISTRATIONDATE,'MM/DD/YYYY'),'WW') as "Week"
FROM CONTRACTS;
```

Comment: When I try  
 `to_char(to_date(REGISTRATIONDATE,'MM/DD/YYYY'),'WW') as "Week" `

I get the error 
`ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string`

Comment: this depend by the format you have in REGISTRATION date ... in my answer  i assume that you have the format  'MM/DD/YYYY' ... but i don't know your real format

Comment: If your field is a date-time then you should only need `to_char(REGISTRATIONDATE,'WW')`

Comment: My field is date-time indeed, when I try it with only `to_char(REGISTRATIONDATE, 'WW')` I, unfortunately, get the error `ORA-1722: invalid number`.

Comment: try remove the time part TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(REGISTRATION , 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'DD/MM/YYYY') ..

Comment: I have tried to remove the spaces, thought maybe that could cause the error but that did not help. Also tried this `TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(REGISTRATION , 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'DD/MM/YYYY')`. Both options give me the `invalid number` error...

Answer (score 0):

This is messy, but it looks like it works:

```
to_char(
        to_date(RegistrationDate,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24-MI-SS') + 
        to_number(to_char(trunc(to_date(RegistrationDate,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24-MI-SS'),'YEAR'),'D'))
        - 2,
        'WW')
```

On the outside you have the solution previous given by others but using the correct date format. In the middle there is an adjustment of a certain number of days to adjust for where the 1st Jan falls. The `trunc` part gets the first of Jan from the date, the `'D'` gets the weekday of 1st Jan. Since `1` represents Sunday, we have to use `-2` to get what we need.

**EDIT**: I may delete this answer later, but it looks to me that the one from @mathguy is the best. See also the comments on that answer for how to extend to a general solution.

But first you need to:

1. Decide what to do dates in Jan before the first Monday, and
2. Resolve the underlying problems in the date which prevent it being converted to dates.

On point 1, if assigning week 0 is not acceptable (you want week 52/53) it gets a bit more complicated, but we'll still be able to help.

As I see it, on point 2, either there is something systematically wrong (perhaps they are timestamps and include fractions of a second) or there are isolated cases of invalid data.

Either the length, or the format, or the specific values don't compute. The error message you got suggests that at least some of the data is "too long", and the code in my comment should help you locate that.

Comment: Whenever you get the chance, do let me know how this worked out. If it turns out to be not quite right, I'm sure we'll be able to fix it. Alternatively, if it does what you need, please mark my answer as 'accepted' by way of a thank you and to help other users find the most helpful info.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have tried this answer, but got the error `ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string`.

Comment: I think this means that your data, or at least one row of your data, does not have that field in the format `'YYYY-MM-DD HH24-MI-SS'`.

Comment: If the data looks mostly to be the right format, you might want to run `select * from CONTRACTS where length(REGISTRATIONDATE)<>length('YYYY-MM-DD HH24-MI-SS');` which should retrieve any "bad" data.

Comment: Depending on what the data issues are, another alternative might be to replace the two occurrences of `to_date(RegistrationDate,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24-MI-SS')` with `to_date(substr(RegistrationDate,1,10),'YYYY-MM-DD')`.

Comment: Again, do let me know how you get on.

Comment: In case it helps, I've updated my answer with some further advice (which would have been a bit long for a comment).