# Return results base on calendar Week

Tags: sql, select, ms-query

I have a table with the following rows.

```
Name    Value   Links   DateSetup
Andrew  10000.00    1   2017-06-06 14:00:44.663
Gerard  35000.00    1   2017-06-07 09:56:18.943
Dominic 70000.00    1   2017-06-07 11:35:56.080
Dominic 25000.00    1   2017-06-08 12:48:02.940
Jim     4800000.00  4   2017-06-08 14:05:00.283
Dominic 600000.00   1   2017-06-08 14:14:15.170
Andrew  350000.00   2   2017-06-09 09:11:19.630
Andrew  75000.00    1   2017-06-09 09:15:58.147
Gerard  115000.00   1   2017-06-09 14:29:18.977
Andrew  200000.00   1   2017-06-09 16:50:32.790
Owen    100000.00   1   2017-06-12 09:33:56.477
Gerard  500000.00   1   2017-06-12 09:49:29.887
Andrew  130000.00   1   2017-06-12 12:03:38.340
Cathal  25500.00    1   2017-06-13 11:11:02.560
Cillian 5000000.00  2   2017-06-13 14:05:21.643
Cillian 8000000.00  2   2017-06-13 14:20:24.777
Cillian 400.00      2   2017-06-13 14:48:51.447
```

I need to run a query to return all results for calendar week 23.

I currently use the following but want to change from providing the between dates to calendar week.

```
SELECT         Name, Value, Links,DateSetup
FROM           setup
WHERE DateSetup BETWEEN '05-06-2017 00:00:00' AND '11-06-2017 00:00:00'
```

Any help would be grateful.

Comment: which DB system are you using?

Comment: For oracle DB https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16530044/how-to-extract-week-number-in-sql

Comment: It is SQL. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As there is no DB tagged:

For SQL Server you could use:

```
SELECT Name
      ,Value
      ,Links
      ,DateSetup
  FROM setup
 WHERE DATEPART(wk, DateSetup) = 23
```

MySQL should work like:

```
SELECT Name
      ,Value
      ,Links
      ,DateSetup
  FROM setup
 WHERE WEEK(DateSetup) = 23
```