# Oracle query for finding the week

Tags: sql, oracle

We have below query to get the current week number from 1970-01-01, but it is written some time back, can you please tell me exactly why it was subtracting 3 from the subtracted date?

```
SELECT
TRUNC((to_number(sysdate-to_date('1970-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'))-3)/7) week from dual
```

Comment: duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16530044/how-to-extract-week-number-in-sql

Comment: Hey @Indent : this question is **not a duplicate** of the thread you linked to. In this question, the OP is counting weeks continuously from January 1, 1970 - not from the beginning of the calendar year. The wording may sound similar, but the problem is really quite different.

Answer (score 1):

1970-01-01 was a Thursday.

The purpose of subtracting three days is to move the start of the week to Monday.

As a note, the first day of the current millenium -- 2001-01-01 -- is conveniently a Monday.  That makes it a convenient reference point.

Comment: This is incorrect - the difference is being reduced by 3 so effectively it is adding three days to move the point of comparison to `1970-01-04` which is a Sunday.

Comment: To further explain MT0's objection (with which I agree): The 3 is "subtracted" from the input date, not from the fixed Thursday date of 1970-01-01. If you use parentheses, the - 3 becomes "1970-01-01 **+** 3" (in parentheses), so it moves you forward to Sunday.

Answer (score 1):

If you put a range of days into it:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae2cc8/19)

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT TRUNC((to_number(dt-to_date('1970-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'))-3)/7)
         week,
       TO_CHAR( dt, 'DY YYYY-MM-DD' ) AS day
FROM ( SELECT TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' ) + LEVEL - 1 AS dt
       FROM   DUAL
       CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 7 )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae2cc8/19/0)**:

```
| WEEK |            DAY |
|------|----------------|
| 2491 | MON 2017-10-02 |
| 2491 | TUE 2017-10-03 |
| 2491 | WED 2017-10-04 |
| 2491 | THU 2017-10-05 |
| 2491 | FRI 2017-10-06 |
| 2491 | SAT 2017-10-07 |
| 2492 | SUN 2017-10-08 |
```

The query is **NOT** translating the day to a Monday but is instead reducing the difference by 3, so effectively calculating the number of full weeks between the current day and Sunday 4th January 1970.

A simplified version of your query would be:

```
SELECT TRUNC( ( SYSDATE - DATE '1970-01-04' ) / 7 ) AS Week
FROM   DUAL;
```

or a version which is more explanatory of the "magic" date:

```
SELECT TRUNC( ( SYSDATE - NEXT_DAY( DATE '1970-01-01', 'SUNDAY' ) ) / 7 ) AS Week
FROM   DUAL;
```

Comment: I agree with the answer. I would NOT use the "simplified version"; if I read the code for the first time, I understand `'1970-01-01'`, and I have to wonder about the `- 3` (I will figure out it has to do with adjusting for the first day of the week, and I will have to do some calculations as you did to see exactly how that works); but `'1970-01-04'` will look really odd, I won't know why *that* magic date was chosen.

Comment: @mathguy Updated with a second "simple" version that is more self-explanatory for the "magic" date.

Comment: Perfect! Now it's both simple and easy to follow the logic.